# The base of a pyramid is a rectangle with the surface area of $S$ and angle between diagonals of $60°$.

Tags: geometry

The base of a pyramid is a rectangle with the surface area of $S$ and angle between diagonals of $60°$. Calculate the volume of the pyramid if the edges are tilted against the base with an angle of $45°$.

I drew the picture. I am aware I need the height of the pyramid. If I drew this correctly I have a billion triangles pretty much and I am not sure where I can get anything helpful. Any tips?

Comment: I think it's impossible. This pyramid does not exist.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Its a problem from my math problem book. Maybe I didn't translate the problem well since the book is in Bosnian?

Comment: It would be helpful. Add a formulation in Bosnian.

Comment: Osnova piramide je pravougaonik čija je površina S i ugao između dijagonala 60°. Odrediti zapreminu piramide ako su bočne ivice nagnute prema ravni osnove pod uglom 45°. @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: Yes, it's the same. The rectangle must be square, which is impossible.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg The result has the 4th square root of 27. That doesn't seem possible since the problem doesn't even state any numbers. This is clearly a mistake in the book then?

Comment: I think so, but wait. Maybe someone will say something another,

Answer (score 0):

The base is a rectangle with sides $a=\sqrt{S/\sqrt3}$ and $\sqrt3a$, and with diagonal $2a$. If lateral edges form an angle of 45° with the base, then the height of the pyramid is half the diagonal of the base, hence $a$. The volume is then:
$$
V={1\over3}Sa={1\over3}\sqrt{S^3\over\sqrt3}.
$$